# Formato JSON em campo LocalDate

Tags: java, json, gson

Pessoal tenho o sequinte registro sendo retornado por uma consulta usando `SpringData`:

```
page = grupoService.findByNomeStartingWithOrderByNomeAsc(2, pageable);
```

Se eu executar o seguinte código:

```
System.out.println(page.getContent().get(0));
```

Ele imprime:

```
Grupo{id=2, dtOperacao='2016-08-26'}
```

Porém quando eu converto para `JSON` (para ser enviado ao `frontend`):

```
return new ResponseEntity<String>(new Gson().toJson(scSelect), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
```

O mesmo converte a data para:

```
{"id": 1, "dtOperacao":{"year":2016,"month":8,"day":26}}
```

Ele porém deveria retornar assim:

```
dtOperacao='2016-08-26'
```

Alguém sabe como resolver isso? Lembrando que preciso continuar usando o `Gson`.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que seja o Serializer. Como não tenho certeza da Classe de Data que vc está usando, caso seja um Date, vc pode usar da seguinte forma:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").create();
```

**EDIT:**
LocalDate ... sorry

use um serializer

```
JsonSerializer<Date> localDateSerializer = new JsonSerializer<Date>() {
  @Override
  public JsonElement serialize(LocalDate date, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext contex) {
    return return new JsonPrimitive(date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE));
  }
};
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
   .registerTypeAdapter(LocalDate.class, localDateSerializer)
   .create();
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu resolvi utilizando essa função no front-end:

```
 function convertLocalDateToServer (date) {
        if (date) {
            return $filter('date')(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

E depois só chamo ela antes do post para corrigir a data:

```
 method: 'POST',
            transformRequest: function (data) {
                if(data.grupo){                     
                    data.grupo.dtOperacao = DateUtils.convertLocalDateToServer(
                            //This convertion is necessary cause the component scselect returns an object date
                            new Date(data.grupo.dtOperacao.year, data.grupo.dtOperacao.month, data.grupo.dtOperacao.day)
                    );                      
                };
                return angular.toJson(data);
```